# Fat arrow function gets rewritten to normal function. 'this' is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to convert my app to Ionic2, and am encountering yet another issue. I have the following code:

```
this.database.query("SELECT whatever FROM tab WHERE field = ?", [someVar]).then(
  (result) => {
                this.database.query...
```

I used the arrow function to make sure I can still have a reference to 'this' and thus make another db call. (Note this.database is a a service of which the query function returns a Promise)

This is however failing with the error "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of null". When I debug, I can indeed see that 'this' is undefined.

When I look at the source code of the emulator, I see following code (function has been added):

```
this.database.query("SELECT whatever FROM tab WHERE field = ?", [someVar]).then(
  function (result) {
                     this.database.query...
```

Is it normal that this is added? Since it breaks my code. Also no other variable is introduced to keep reference to 'this'.
How to solve this?

My configuration:

```
Typescript 2 installed

"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"ionic-native": "2.2.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "0.6.21"

"@ionic/app-scripts": "^0.0.36",
"typescript": "^2.0.3"

"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"target": "es5"
```

---

edit: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/ox5kmvBYObCmliAV1aVy) reproduction forked from an Ionic2 sample, there it DOES work
edit2: Above plunker uses Typescript 1.7 lib. I tried to make a new [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/9K5c9lD5AKq9zxpADWKL), but can't get it to work

---

FINAL EDIT
Finally, it works now but I cannot point out why. I'm tracking al my changes in the source code through git, and the only thing different is that in the meantime I tried using ES6 as target and I added -but removed again- crosswalk. Also I build for Android in the meantime Maybe the ES6 transpiling or android build has left some code that is useful? Very annoying to not know the cause..

Anyway, I'm probably not going to try analysing any further since I keep running into problems with Ionic2. It doesn't seem stable enough yet. Current issues are amongst others: black screens, white screens, content behind header, wrong app icon on ios, often strange behaviour, layout problems on Android,.. So for the time being I'll revert to Ionic1 :'(

Comment: Shouldn't you target es6 in order to use arrow functions? Arrow functions were added in es6 not es5...

Comment: Very unlikely anyone will be able to help you without a minimal self-contained repro

Comment: @ahitt6345 I don't use transpilers myself, but isn't this saying that the _output_ of the transpiler should be ES5, not the _input_ ?

Comment: The compiler indeed "rewrites" the arrow function to anonymous one, but it saves the scope with `var _this = this;` before the function. If your `this` is undefined then maybe the function which contains it already has no scope for this.

Comment: @S. Roose can you please `console.log(this)` inside of the function, please and give us the output?

Comment: @ahitt6345 the error already indicates that it's `null`

Comment: @ahitt6345 Thats indeed gives 'undefined'

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I'm new to all this, bit I managed to fork a Plunkr where I reproduced my code. (Un)fortunately, there the issue was not present! See https://plnkr.co/ox5kmvBYObCmliAV1aVy
Not sure what is different in that environment, but I guess it has to do with the Typescript preprocessing that is happening in my Visual Studio project?

Comment: @ahitt6345 I read that I should NOT use ES6 because it is not yet well supported by the mobile devices. Which seems true from looking at this table:http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ Would you advise otherwise? Does your reply mean that Typescript/ES5 is not supporting this (Or only as a fancy shortkey)?

Comment: TypeScript supports fat arrow functions correctly. Without seeing your build pipeline it's impossible to know what's going wrong.